# ftp_put "Failed to establish connection" error with FTP SSL connection on some server

Tags: php, ssl, ftp, vsftpd

I've created a PHP script in order to make backups of web projects. It consists of make a .tar.gz archive, and the send it to a personal FTP Server (with vsftpd).

From many Web server it works fine, but from one particular Web server the script not works correctly.

Here the part of FTP connection:

```
$connessione = ftp_ssl_connect($ftpServer, $ftpPort, 300);
if($connessione == false)
{
    echo("connection failed.\n");
    return false;
}
echo("Connection established.\n");
echo("Authenticating for "  .$username . " ...\n");
$resLogin = ftp_login($connessione, $username, $password);
if(!$resLogin)
{
    echo("authentication failed.\n");
    return false;
}
ftp_pasv($connessione, false);

$workingDir = ftp_pwd($connessione);
echo("entering on " . $workingDir . "\n");
echo("Uploading file ... \n");
$fullFilePath = __DIR__ . "/" . $filePath;
$result = ftp_put($connessione, $ftpPath . $file, $fullFilePath, FTP_BINARY);
if($result)
    echo("Upload completed.\n");
else
    echo("Some error occurred.\n");
ftp_close($connessione);
```

The error returned by `ftp_put` call is:

> PHP Warning:  ftp_put(): Failed to establish connection.

Answer (score 3):

You are explicitly using an FTP *active* mode. I'm even surprised that works for you on most servers. Do not use the *active* mode, use a *passive* mode.

```
ftp_pasv($connessione, true);
```

For the active mode to work, your webserver has to have firewall and NAT configured to allow incoming FTP data connections. For details, see *my* article on the [active and passive FTP connection modes](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftp_modes).